# How to Burn Bootloader with custom Fuses

Tags: bootloader, fuses, arduino-as-isp

I have a Atmega328p IC without external Crystal (My target).

When I use a arduino to burn the bootloader to my target, the Arduino as ISP sketch changes the fuses of my target, so it tries to use its external crystal, which is not connected, So it cannot proceed the bootloader burn.

[image: external crystal]

How can I modify the Fuse settings while Burning bootloader with arduino?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either adjust the current board fuse settings in `boards.txt` or create a new board variant that matches your settings.

For example the Uno is set up with:

```
uno.bootloader.tool=avrdude
uno.bootloader.low_fuses=0xFF
uno.bootloader.high_fuses=0xDE
uno.bootloader.extended_fuses=0xFD
uno.bootloader.unlock_bits=0x3F
uno.bootloader.lock_bits=0x0F
uno.bootloader.file=optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex
```

Comment: and after changing this file, I needed to re-start the arduino.exe, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [MiniCore](https://github.com/MCUdude/MiniCore) boards support package for Arduino IDE to work with nonstandard AVR boards or breadboard setups. This core has many settings in Tools menu to set different parameters of the board.